# Android Sqlite query Execution Break

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a DB for some searching.  When the user starts typing I perform a search in the DB, executing the query inside an async task.  I can cancel the async task, but the query once it has started executing, wont stop, so my searches becomes slow.  It should executing the queries one at a time.

I need to cancel the current execution and start the search with a new search string. How can I break current execution of the query? I have read SQL interrupt, but I don't understand how I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. It's on native level. SQLite provides `void sqlite3_interrupt(sqlite3*);` in C interface.